# Visual Studio 2010 Designer opens an empty popup

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

recently I was working on Windows Form Project on Visual Studio 2010, when it started to show this strange behavior. Whenever I open a windows form in designer, an empty control is created and hangs in the middle of the screen.

The only "non standard" feature I am using, I extend each control with a parent user control as following

```
    public partial class MainUserControl : UserControl
    {
    ...
    }
    public partial class UserControl : MainUserControl
    {
    ...
    }
```

[image: StrangePopup]

Any hint on how to fix?

Comment: Nothing I recognize.  Beware of code in your control running at design time.  You prevent that from having side-effects like this by using the DesignTime property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficolt to give a comprehensive explanation on how I solved it but it does seem like one of the many designer bugs that may eventually appear when extending a user control from another user control.

By creating a simpler constructor to "trick" the designer the popup went away.

Always try to have something like

```
public class BaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected BaseUserControl(... [many params passed])
    {
        ...
    }

    protected BaseUserControl()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and avoid

```
protected BaseUserControl() : BaseUserControl(... [many params passed])
{
    ...
}
```